# how to show Special Characters when parsing xml file in Android

Tags: android, xml

I have an xml file and when parsing it, Special Characters like \uFD3F are shown as it is, not as represented symbol, 
TextView and Strings.xml shows it correctlly
can anyone help me with this prblem?
thanks

Comment: Can you paste some sample code so we know what you've already tried?

Comment: please have a look at my xml file and codes

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to add Special Characters to xml file by using
&#x+ hex code+;
for example:"&#xae" for ®

or &# Decimal Code+;
for example: "&#174" for ®